# EGR Valve Location on Mercedes Vito W639 109CDI

Tags: mercedes-benz, egr

My Vito fails to rev above 3,000RPM and I suspect the EGR valve may be at fault.

My first step is to identify the location of the EGR valve on the manifold.

This looks like it may be the EGR valve at the back of the engine bay:

[image: Potential EGR Valve Closeup]

Here is a longshot of the same part of the engine bay where the suspect valve is at the back of the engine bay:

[image: Potential EGR Valve Distance shot]

Have I identified the EGR valve correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it turns out that it is indeed the EGR valve on a Vito 109 CDI engine.